# Problems with MySQL Natural language search not returning expected result

Tags: mysql, search

My current query:

```
SELECT SCHOOL_NAME, TOWN, POSTCODE, COUNTRY, COUNTY, id FROM schools
WHERE MATCH(LA_NAME, SCHOOL_NAME, STREET, LOCALITY, ADDRESS3, TOWN, COUNTY)
AGAINST ("southwark") AND COUNTRY = 'gb' limit 0,5;
```

Is returning (Removed some data for sanity):

```
Southwark Park School       
The Cathedral School of St Saviour and St Mary Ove...   
Harris Academy Bermondsey   
Southwark Inclusive Learning Service KS3, KS4 & Si...   
St George's Cathedral Catholic Primary School
```

Note that Southwark Primary School is not included in these results

If I do this query

```
SELECT SCHOOL_NAME FROM  schools WHERE `SCHOOL_NAME` LIKE  '%southwark%' LIMIT 0 , 3
```

My returned response is

```
City of London Academy (Southwark)
Southwark Primary School
Southwark Park School
```

Key point: Southwark Primary School is available in the results here.  This is what is missing from the natural language search results.

Explain shows:

```
id  select_type table   type     possible_keys  key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE          schools fulltext LA_NAME    LA_NAME 0       1   Using where
```

So Natural language search for some reason is not performing as well as it should, I have tried playing with Boolean mode but that doesn't work.  Can anyone shed any light on what I might be doing wrong?

**Note:** If I change the limit on the first query to 0,50 I still don't see Southwark primary school.

**Edit:** If I change the Natural Language Search to limit 0,240 I get the result as result #238.

**Edit #2**

```
myisam_ftdump mydatabase/schools 1 -c | grep southwark
```

Returns:

```
108         7.7915840 southwark
```

**Update: So it looks like LA_NAME has a value of Southwark so a lot of values contain that.  I used myisam_ftdump to isolate this issue.  I can now ponder on a fix.**

**Fixed:** So to fix this I had to modify my fulltext to not include LA_NAME, I also dropped some other data that was not really required IE postcode.  I also modified my MySQL query to no longer use the fields that I dropped.

Comment: I don't know about the natural language searches on mysql, but in sql server there is a weight associated with hits. Maybe this item is way done the list past 50 due to something simillar. See if it's ever in the lst.

Comment: So why do you think it should be higher up than #238 ?

Comment: Because the other results aren't relevant at all so I have no idea why they are appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Have encountered similar challenges with Natural Language Search.  your remark about it being contained in LA_NAME might be answered at [12.9.1. Natural Language Full-Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html):

> The search result is empty because the word “MySQL” is present in at
>   least 50% of the rows. As such, it is effectively treated as a
>   stopword.